# How can I make my sed command work on OSX as well as Ubuntu

Tags: sed

I like customizing my PS1 prompt and including the current directory.

I also have several other items such as time, user, git branch and the like, i.e.

[image]

However one problem is that when my current directory is many layers 'deep' such as `/home/durrantmm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/app/views` there is too much text. (btw I carriage return at the end within my PS1 prompt setting anyway so my actual $ is back on the left, that is not the issue here).

So I have a solution for that, to use this for the location part:

```
LOCATION='\033[01;34m\]`pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+/[^/]\+/\).*\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+\)/\?#\1_\2#g"`'
```

not pretty, but it does the job and I then combine it with the other stuff (not shown, not needed here) and I get "first 3 levels _ last two levels" for the directories, i.e.

[image]

Unfortunately though on my mac the sed part isn't working correctly and I get:

[image]
[this is actually from my Linux machine, I faked it to show what it looks like on my mac in case you are wondering).

How can I get the `3_2` format for the current directory on my mac ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\+` and `\?` parts of your `sed` command are GNU extensions - POSIX compatible `sed` cannot use these aspects of extended regex at all. Instead you can use `\{1,\}` and `\{0,1\}`. Try this:

```
LOCATION='\033[01;34m\]`pwd |
  sed "s#\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/\).*\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}\)/\{0,1\}#\1_\2#g"`'
```

For more information on this see - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/sed.html and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html.

Alternatively, you can enable extended regular expressions on OSX `sed` using `-E`. With this you could do:

```
LOCATION='\033[01;34m\]`pwd |
  sed -E "s#\(/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/\).*\(/[^/]+/[^/]+\)/?#\1_\2#g"`'
```

However, this won't work on GNU `sed` (it uses `-r` for this). Using a POSIX solution will give better portability.